# Laravel 'belongsTo' relationship not working, no idea why

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a `ClientCourier` class, here's the basic migration:

```
   Schema::create('client_couriers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
        $table->foreign('client_id')
            ->references('id')->on('clients')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');

        // the same client cannot have two couriers with the same name
        $table->unique(['name', 'client_id']);
    });
```

And here's the model:

```
class ClientCourier extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function services() {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientCourierService::class);
    }
}
```

Each `ClientCourier` can have man `ClientCourierServices`, hence the `hasMany` relationship above.

Here's the migration for the `ClientCourierService`:

```
  Schema::create('client_courier_services', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
        $table->foreign('client_id')
            ->references('id')->on('clients')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('client_courier_id');
        $table->foreign('client_courier_id')
            ->references('id')->on('client_couriers')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code', 64);

        // the same courier cannot have two services with the same name
        $table->unique(['name', 'client_courier_id']);
        // the same client cannot have two services with the same code
        $table->unique(['code', 'client_id']);
    });
```

And here's the model:

```
class ClientCourierService extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'client_id' => 'integer',
        'client_courier_id' => 'integer'
    ];

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function courier() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ClientCourier::class);
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, my `client_courier_services` table foreign-keys with `client_couriers` on the column `client_courier_id`.

Now, when I iterate over my services and try to get the matching `Courier` from the `Service`, it doesn't work:

```
$services = ClientCourierService::get();
foreach($services as $service) {
    $fromModel = $service->courier;
    $fromDb = ClientCourier::where(['id' => $service->client_courier_id]);
    // fromModel is null
    // fromDb is the correct courier
}
```

My other relationships work. Getting the services from the courier via `$courier->services` works. Getting the client from either the `ClientCourier` class or the `ClientCourierService` class works. `$service->courier;` should work by all accounts, but it doesn't, and I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you use `courier()` as a method name it expects that the column name is `courier_id` hence the reason why there is no result. Try to provide the column name yourself as a second parameter.. for example:

```
public function courier() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ClientCourier::class, 'client_courier_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Your bit of code fixed the issue but I don't understand. My `services` function in `ClientCourier` class works fine despite the fact that it should apparently be wrong for the same reason...

Comment: hmm, then it is opposite direction, the `id` from the `ClientCourier` is being matched, so if you have that column called differently then it will be confused and you will need to pass it. But in the ClientCourierService the column is also correct. So no changes needed there.

Comment: @TKoL The linked question has your answer, but basically the `belongsTo` relationship builds the foreign key based on the name of the function. The `hasOne`\`hasMany` side of the relationship builds the foreign key based on the name of the class in which it is defined. So, in your `ClientCourier::services()` function (`hasMany`), the foreign key will correctly build as `client_courier_id` (using the class name). However, in your `ClientCourierService::courier()` function (`belongsTo`), the foreign key will incorrectly build as `courier_id` (using the function name).

Comment: @TKoL You either need to rename `ClientCourierService::courier()` to `ClientCourierService::clientCourier()`, or you need to pass in the explicit foreign key name as the second parameter to the `belongsTo()` function.